# Ruby: getting variable name

Tags: ruby

How can I get a variable name? E.g.,

```
def get_var_name(var)
  # return variable name
end

myname = nil
get_var_name myname #=> myname
```

Initial purpose:

```
somevar = "value"

puti somevar #=> somevar = "value"
# that is a shortage for
# `puts "somevar = #{somevar.inspect}"`
```

My try:

```
def puti(symb)
  var_name  = symb.to_s
  var_value = eval(var_name)
  puts "#{var_name} = #{var_value.inspect}"
end
puti :@somevar # that actually will work only with class vars or whatever considering var scope;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356749 This is more closer to your requirement.

Comment: another use case is using variable name as hash key like `es` for example: `a=1; b=2; h=Hash[a,b]; puts h` supposed to be: `{a: 1, b: 2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you cannot implement a `puti` and directly call `puti a_var` to get the output as `a_var = value of a_var`. At the body of `puti`, Ruby sees only the formal parameter names of `puti`, it cannot infer the actual parameter names.

In some other language like C/C++, you can use [**Macro**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macros.html) to implement your `puti`. That's another story.

However, you can implement `put :a_var`, with the help of [Continuation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Continuation.html). In another question "[Can you eval code in the context of a caller in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356749)", [Sony Santos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/632916/sony-santos) has provided a [caller_binding](http://rubychallenger.blogspot.com/2011/07/caller-binding.html) implementation to get the binding of the caller (something like the perl caller function).

The implementation should be altered a bit, because `callcc` returns the return value of the block at its first returning. So you'll get an instance of `Continuation` rather than `nil`. Here is the updated version:

```rb
require 'continuation' if RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9.0'

def caller_binding
  cc = nil     # must be present to work within lambda
  count = 0    # counter of returns

  set_trace_func lambda { |event, file, lineno, id, binding, klass|
    # First return gets to the caller of this method
    # (which already know its own binding).
    # Second return gets to the caller of the caller.
    # That's we want!
    if count == 2
      set_trace_func nil
      # Will return the binding to the callcc below.
      cc.call binding
    elsif event == "return"
      count += 1
    end
  }
  # First time it'll set the cc and return nil to the caller.
  # So it's important to the caller to return again
  # if it gets nil, then we get the second return.
  # Second time it'll return the binding.
  return callcc { |cont| cc = cont; nil }
end

# Example of use:

def puti *vars
  return unless bnd = caller_binding
  vars.each do |s|
    value = eval s.to_s, bnd
    puts "#{s} = #{value.inspect}"
  end
end

a = 1
b = 2
puti :a, :b
e = 1 # place holder...

# => a = 1
#    b = 2
```

Note the `puti` should not be the last statement of your program, otherwise the ruby interpreter will terminate immediately and the trace function has no chance to run. So that's the point of the last "place holder" line.

Comment: It's hacky but i like this one. Thank you;

Answer (score 8):

You need to carry across the binding of the current variable scope, which you do with [the Binding class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Binding.html):

```
def puti(symb, the_binding)
  var_name  = symb.to_s
  var_value = eval(var_name, the_binding)
  puts "#{var_name} = #{var_value.inspect}"
end

somevar = 3

puti :somevar, binding   # Call the binding() method

   #=> outputs "somevar = 3"
```

The `binding()` method gives a Binding object which remembers the context at the point the method was called. You then pass a binding into `eval()`, and it evaluates the variable in that context.