# Ruby - Automatically pass binding() to method like eval?

Tags: ruby, scope

Ruby 2.7.0

I am writing something similar in vein to the 'eval' method, and I'm realizing there seems to be some magic happening.

Ruby's Kernel#eval has the ability to be given a binding, but somehow when a binding is not specified it manages to get the callers binding as a default.

As an example:

```
def my_eval(str)
  "?? how do I access #{str}"
  #foo  # <- NameError
end

foo = "BAR"

var = 'foo'
puts "EVAL: "+eval(var)
puts "MY_EVAL: "+my_eval(var)
```

We call eval with 'var' which is a string containing the word "foo".  Somehow eval is able to access the callers local_variables as if it had magically been called with 'binding()'

The my_eval method is not so lucky.  How can I get the callers binding or have the binding automatically sent with the method call, without having to require all users of the method to add "binding()" to the list of arguments?

Or is this magic confined only to Kernel#eval and can't be replicated?

EDIT:

After discovering the similar question:  [How can I get the binding from method_missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1314592/how-can-i-get-the-binding-from-method-missing/1315612#1315612)

I have come up with a (slightly less fragile) answer using TracePoint (which is the clean version of set_trace_func).

But that requires running a simple debugger on top of my code, which is not only concerning, but it's massively slowing down my code (the simple binding tracking is running 4x slower!).  Does ruby have this type of internals reflection without using a tracer, or possibly writing my_eval as a C function?

Comment: I've discovered the "binding_of_caller" gem, which depends on RubyVM::DebugInspector (for MRI, at least), which is another gem that has C extensions to it, which is making me start to suspect that this can't be done.  I'm surprised to see that eval might be cheating in this regard.  :(

Comment: Please note your context is different if you for instance create a method `def kernel_eval(str); eval(str); end;` and call as `kernel_eval(var)` the result is the same because `foo` is undefined in that scope.

Comment: @engineersmnky exactly the point.  So how could we have kernel_eval get the scope of the caller in the same way eval does?  eval is just a method.

Comment: Every programming language will always have some fundamental operations that cannot be explained within the programming language itself. In Ruby, these include, among other things, `Class#allocate` which interacts directly with memory, `Module#private`, `Module#protected`, `Module#public`, `Module#define_method`, `Module#define_singleton_method`, and the various `*_eval` and `*_exec` methods. In other languages, for example, consider that Java has overloaded operators but no operator overloading.

Comment: @DavidLjungMadisonStellar additionally you could follow through rubinius (which started out as a ruby VM written in ruby) source code to see how they implemented [Kernel#eval](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/kernel.rb#L1110) and [Kernel#caller](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/kernel.rb#L380). While I did not take the time to track it back but it could provide you with a useful direction.

Comment: I checked rubinius, and it looks like it implements it's own bindings, so I think it's just tracking all that itself, and that doesn't really help me figure it out on MRI.

So I'm back to square one.  I think at this point I need to write a C api to my ruby call so that it can get the internals, but need to figure out how to read vm_eval.c to do that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out there's no easy answer.  I've compiled a list here:

[Ruby: Binding of Caller Solutions](https://davesource.com/Solutions/20220610.ruby-binding-of-caller/)

And it breaks down to the following possibilities (expanded on in the link above):

1. Use binding_of_caller gem
2. Use a really sneaky pure ruby trick that only works if your method takes no args (involving define_singleton_method and then composing (>>) Object::method(:binding) with your method).  See examples at https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/18487
3. Use TracePoint API for a pure ruby solution that is amazingly slow
4. Call rb_eval_string_protect("binding") inside of a C extension which, until Ruby 3.2.0, will get you all of the binding (but with a corrupted receiver)
5. Use my cut down C extension that takes the important bits out of the gem that binding_of_caller depends upon (debug_inspector)